# How to pass a .txt file as a function argument in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, file, tuples

I have difficulties with my program. I am asked to write a code that prompts the user for a file input (.txt file) and then passes it to my first function as an argument. The is the code I wrote:

```
filepath = input('Enter your file here: ')
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
        print('Line {}: {}'.format(cnt, line))
```

And here are the functions:

```
string = 'abcd acbd adbc adcb 100,000'

def function_one(string):
    modify_one = string.split(' ')
    my_tuple = (modify_one[3], modify_one[2], modify_one[4], modify_one[1], 
    modify_one[0])
    print(my_tuple)

def function_two(my_tuple):
    print(my_tuple)
    formatted = '|{:<15} | {:<15} | {:<8} | {:<15} | {:<15}|'.format(*my_tuple)
    print(formatted)

function_one(string)
function_two(my_tuple)
```

So function_one takes a string as an argument, splits it and turns it into a tuple. The tuple is passed to function_two which formats it into something like a table.

**IMPORTANT** 
I want to mention that I wrote the two codes on separate files so they are not connected to each other yet. The idea is functions to perform their operations on the text which is inside the .txt file. However, I really struggle with this part. Both codes work properly separately. I apologize if the title is misleading or I haven't structured my question good enough. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You simply need to feed the function from the main loop. inside the loop in your first code the iterates the file using `enumerate` add `function_one(line)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't know how to do it...

Comment: You asked and deleted the exact same question 1 hour ago... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226991/how-to-pass-a-txt-file-as-an-function-argument-in-python

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev exactly as it is written: put the line `function_one(line)` inside the loop after `print('Line {}: {}'.format(cnt, line))`

Comment: Don’t define a function inside of another one.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import the function in the other module like so:

```
from function_one_file import function_one

a = input()
function_one(a)
```